# XACML Custom RuleCombining algorithm in wso2

Tags: algorithm, xacml, abac, balana, wso2-identity-server

I am a user of WSO2 IS,
I need to add a custom RuleCombining algorithm in my WSO2 IS.
I am using this [example](http://xacmlinfo.org/2012/12/18/initializing-configured-balana-instance-for-wso2-identity-server/) of balana and when I create [this](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/trunk/commons/balana/modules/balana-samples/custom-combining-algo/resources/custom-algo-policy-alice.xml)
Policy in the WSO2 IS I obtain this Error: Unsupported Entitlement Policy. Policy can not be parsed, and this is the log of the WSO2 IS:

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.pap.PAPPolicyReader} -  Error while parsing the policy org.wso2.balana.ParsingException: Error parsing combining algorithm in Policy 
Caused by: org.wso2.balana.UnknownIdentifierException: unknown combining algId: urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:rule-combining-algorithm:highest-effect
        at org.wso2.balana.combine.BaseCombiningAlgFactory.createAlgorithm(BaseCombiningAlgFactory.java:138)
        at org.wso2.balana.AbstractPolicy.<init>(AbstractPolicy.java:237)
```

**Edited:**

Thank you for the answer David,

In the same example page we can read that we can extend the WSO2 IS with custom functions, algorithms and data-types, adding a balana configuration file:

> However, If you want to ask WSO2 Identity Server to initialize the
>   Balana by reading configuration file. You can do it by creating a new
>   configuration file called “balana-config.xml” under the
>   /repository/conf/security directory. As an example, Say you
>   want to add new rule combining algorithm to work with WSO2 Identity
>   Server entitlement engine. Then you can follow same way that is
>   configuring it with Balana. Please refer this blog post for more
>   details. However I would like to summarize the step to follow.

But after following the steps it doesn't seem to be working.

Any other help in this issue will be appreciated.

I am considering axiomatics as XACML engine, but it seem very difficult to get a version for testing or inception purposes. Can you give me any light on this concern?.

Comment: request an account at https://support.axiomatics.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to extend the WSO2 IS with custom combining algoritm. The post you link to states:

> WSO2 Identity Server does not deal with those Because most of the
>   applications use standard set of functions, attribute and combining
>   algorithms that is defined in the XACML specification. Therefore, by
>   default, WSO2 Identity Server initializes the Balana instance with
>   default standard configuration.

If you want to use a combining algorithm, use the [Axiomatics Policy Server](http://www.axiomatics.com/solutions/products/authorization-for-applications/axiomatics-policy-server.html) instead.

Side note: why do you want a combining algorithm? You should try to stick to standard combining algorithms. What does `urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:rule-combining-algorithm:highest-effect` do? Also you cannot use the OASIS namespace for your combining algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for the answer David,

Comment: @Miguel my pleasure. Don't forget to accept if it is correct. Also, what's your rationale for the custom comb. algo? What do you want to do with it?